# Javascript ConfirmBox not showing when called in Update Panel

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I'm trying to show a javascript confirm box whenever a link button in my repeater is clicked and has passed some condition.

My Repeater is inside an Update Panel that is inside an Ajax Accordion Content Template.

```
<Accordion><UpdatePanel><Repeater>this is where the link button is</Repeater></UpdatePanel></Accordion>
```

Here's my code, i put it inside a Repeater_ItemCommand method:

```
 Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "ConfirmDelete", "return confirm('Are You Sure Want To Delete?');");
```

I've looked into several code solution, but still isn't working.
What did i do wrong?

UPDATE:

If i call the javascript from the html. it works just fine.
Code:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lbDelete" runat="server" OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure want to delete?');">Delete</asp:LinkButton>
```

But i still cant call it from code behind

Comment: Where is that line of code? In the Postback method?

Comment: @Jeremy Thompson - in the repeater item command method

Comment: strange I don't think confirm is going to work in this way!!

Comment: Hello See my edit code.Its working perfect to me

string script = "alert('Are You Sure Want To Delete?');";
        ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "ConfirmDelete", script, true);

Comment: @Shekhar why is that?

Comment: you won't get the value of confirm in the c# so you can not take any decision in code behind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it using Repeater_ItemDataBound Event. you just have to register the javascript with button/linkbutton when the control is getting binded. following code block will give you a rough idea

```
    protected void rpt_ItemDataBound(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
    {
      if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType==  ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
       {
          LinkButton btn = (LinkButton)e.Item.FindControl("btnDelete");
          btn.Attributes.Add("onclick", "if ( ! confirm( 'Delete this record?' )) return false; ");

       } 
    }
```

This will work even if your control is in ajax accordian panels.

This way the script will be binded to each linkbutton item in item template. This code looks for Item or AlternatingItem rows, finds the btnDelete control using the FindControl method, and then adds the onclick attribute to the Attributes collection. The result is that when the user clicks the Delete LinkButton, an OK/Cancel dialog pops up to confirm the delete.

You can find more information on the same using following reference link

[Reference](http://www.developer.com/net/asp/article.php/3609851/ASPNET-Tip-Use-the-ItemDataBound-Event-of-a-Repeater.htm)

Answer (score 1):

Try this (with the fourth parameter set to `true`):

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "ConfirmDelete", "return confirm('Are You Sure Want To Delete?');", true);
```

Comment: still isn't working. Is it because my repeater is inside an ajax accordion control??

Comment: Where are you calling this `RegisterStartupScript`? Edit N/M, just saw your comment above...

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
page.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "confirmDelete", "return confirm('confirm?\.');", true);
```

check this also:http://forums.asp.net/t/1363887.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(string), "ConfirmDelete", 
    "return confirm('Are You Sure Want To Delete?');", true);
```

**Edit**:

**Sample for
Client side add this**

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function ShowConfirmation() {
            if (confirm("Are You Sure Want To Delete?") == true) {
                //Calling the server side code after confirmation from the user
                alert("Deleted");
            }
        }
    </script>
```

**Server side c# code**

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "showAl", "ShowConfirmation();", true);
```

Comment: sorry for the late reply, i was out for lunch. But still, the solution didn't work :(

Comment: yes, i was using your edited code only. And i've tried it again, and still didnt work

Answer (score 1):

Use [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/uk-UA/sharepointdevelopmentlegacy/thread/d94e1c53-9e6f-4b2b-8ab8-0538aeedba31) sample

```
 string sJs = "function ConfirmDelete() { return confirm("Are you sure?"); }
      Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(GetType(), "jscode", sJs, true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your should put the js on the repeater this way.

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rep">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnDelete" CommandName="ConfirmDelete" OnClientClick="return confirm('Are You Sure Want To Delete?');" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Also, during data bind, you need to set the `ID` to the button's `CommandArgument` property so that in your  repeater's item command, you can know which one to delete.

Comment: yes i can do it just fine with this, but the problem is i want to call the javascript from the behind code. is there any way to achieve that?

Comment: Let me try to understand... 1. user clicks on Delete button and page posts back.  2. code behind sends confirm button to client.  3. user clicks on confirm button and page post back again.  4. code behind deletes the record.   is that right?

Comment: yes. But before the confirm button shows up to the user, i want to validate if the user have the privilege to delete the record or not. if the user don't have the privilege then the confirmation box wont be shown.

Comment: @ricojohari, I really think you shouldn't do it that way. It's complicated and costing an extra round trip. Is there a reason why you like to do it that way?

Comment: yes, it's a custom in my company. I think it's because of the update panel. But if there is no other way, then i guess ill just call it from the html

Comment: @ricojohari, you should improve the 'custom' by not following it then. I can't see anything can be gained from it or a technical reason requiring it.